# Understanding ADMM: how is it applied to this particular problem?

Tags: inequality, optimization, convex-optimization

While reading [Boyd's paper on ADMM](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) I encountered an issue.

Consider the following problem:

**Problem.** *Minimize $f(u) + g(v)$ subject to $Au + Bv = c$, where $f$ and $g$ are closed, proper, convex and differentiable.*

Denote by $\lambda$ the dual variable. On page 18 of the paper, it is stated that the necessary and sufficient optimality conditions for the above problem are: 
\begin{align}
Au^* + Bv^* &= c\\
\nabla f(u^*) + A^T\lambda^* &= 0\\
\nabla g(v^*) + B^T\lambda^* &= 0.
\end{align}
(I changed the names of the variables, sorry for the inconvenience.)

Now consider the following special case:

Let $$u=(x,t)\in \mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{T}, \quad v=(y,z)\in \mathcal{Y}\times\mathcal{Z}, \quad f(u) = h(x) + at, \ a\neq 0$$ 
where **$\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{Z},\mathcal{T}$ are closed and convex**.
and $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\ 
 -1& 0
\end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},c=0,\lambda = (\lambda_y,\lambda_z)$$

(i.e. the problem becomes *Minimize* $h(x) + at + g(y,z)$ *subject to* $y=x,z=x$).

The second optimality condition above becomes
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla h(x^*)\\ 
a
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_y^*\\ 
\lambda_z^*
\end{bmatrix} = 0$$
Or equivalently
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla h(x^*) - \lambda_y^* - \lambda_z^*\\ 
a
\end{bmatrix}  = 0,$$
which can not be achieved because $a\neq 0$!

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for your discussions!

---

**Update:** The motivation of the above example comes from the following problem I encountered in practice:

Minimize $(a+c+d)^Tx_1 + b^Tx_2$ subject to $(x_1,x_2)\in \mathcal X$, where $\mathcal X$ is a closed convex set defined by $$\mathcal X = \left\{(x_1,x_2)\middle| \begin{matrix}
(x_1,x_2) \text{ satisfy some condition } (1), \\ 
x_1 \text{ satisfies some condition } (2),\\ 
x_1 \text{ satisfies some condition } (3)
\end{matrix}\right\}$$

Denote 
\begin{align}
\mathcal X_1 &= \left\{(x_1,x_2)\mid 
(x_1,x_2) \text{ satisfy condition } (1)\right\}\\
\mathcal Y &= \left\{x_1 \mid 
x_1 \text{ satisfies condition } (2)\right\}\\
\mathcal Z &= \left\{x_1 \mid 
x_1 \text{ satisfies condition } (3)\right\}
\end{align} 
Suppose that the original optimization problem is very hard, but the problems of minimizing any quadratic function over (only) one of the set $\mathcal X_1, \mathcal Y, \mathcal Z$ are easy (minimizing over the intersection of any two sets among them is hard as well).

We can thus decompose the problem using ADMM by reformulating it as:

Minimize $a^Tx_1 + b^Tx_2 + c^Ty +d^Tz$ subject to $y=x_1, z=x_1, (x_1,x_2) \in \mathcal X_1, y\in\mathcal Y, z\in\mathcal Z$.

Can we apply ADMM now, if $\mathcal X_1, \mathcal Y, \mathcal Z$ are closed and convex? What are the optimality conditions then?

Comment: I've the impression that you're trying to translate an original problem into ADMM format, but you're not doing it right. For example what is $g$ ? What do you mean by "$y=x$" when there is the possibility that $\mathcal X \ne \mathcal Y$ ? etc. If you can post the original problem here, then I can 1) tell we what the ADMM equivalent should be 2) what the optimality conditions are

Comment: Hi @dohmatob. Please see my update. Thanks.

Comment: I would formulate your problem as minimizing $f(u) + g(v)$ subject to $Au+Bv=0$ as you have above, but with $f(x_1,x_2) = \langle\text{your original objective}\rangle + \chi_{\mathcal X_1}(x_1,x_2)$ and $g(y,z) = \chi_{\mathcal Y}(y) + \chi_{\mathcal Z}(z)$. Here $\chi_{\mathcal A}$ is the indicator function of the set $\mathcal A$, i.e. $0$ inside and $\infty$ outside.

Comment: @Rahul: Yes by this we can get rid of the sets, but ADMM should also work with my formulation, right? In this paper for example: http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2015/06/4951.pdf, they stated ADMM with closed convex sets too, instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yes but the optimality conditions as stated in the Boyd et al. paper only apply when the domain is $\mathbb R^n$. What you are trying to do is like minimizing $f(x)=x$ over $x\in[-1,1]$ and being surprised that the unconstrained optimality condition $f'(x)=0$ is unsatisfiable.

Comment: @Rahul: I think I have found an answer. The general optimality conditions are stated in Definition 16 (page 14) of this paper: http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2015/06/4954.pdf